# Linux RDP. Ошибка - о нет! Что то пошло не так

Tags: linux, windows, rdp

Скачал и настроил xrdp. Захожу логинюсь, чёрный экран после него пишет о нет. что то пошло не так. Уже и переустанавливал и ребутил. Что делать? [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Модерация которая мне написала, что это вопрос не по тему. 1. Тут нет тем. 2. Это связано с темами на этом форуме.

Comment: Эээ... поставь `remmina` и будет тебе счастье.

Comment: @donRumata у него сервер rdp, а не клиент)

Comment: А, тупанул. Ну тогда лучше посмотреть в сторону `x2go`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сессия гнома очень сильно зависит от GL ускорения. На xrdp оно практически не реализовано. Настроить его я даже не пытался. Я вижу 2 простых выхода:

Использовать более простые сессии, например, `gnome-session-flashback`.

apt install gnome-session-flashback

и выбрать "Gnome Flashback (Metacity)" в настройках при логине.

Для установки на определенном пользователе:

```
echo exec /usr/libexec/gnome-flashback-metacity > ~/.xsession
```

Или для всех в файле /etc/xrdp/startwm.sh добавить строку с   STARTUP

```
#!/bin/sh
# xrdp X session start script (c) 2015, 2017, 2021 mirabilos
# published under The MirOS Licence

# Rely on /etc/pam.d/xrdp-sesman using pam_env to load both
# /etc/environment and /etc/default/locale to initialise the
# locale and the user environment properly.

if test -r /etc/profile; then
        . /etc/profile
fi

export STARTUP=/usr/libexec/gnome-flashback-metacity

test -x /etc/X11/Xsession && exec /etc/X11/Xsession
exec /bin/sh /etc/X11/Xsession
```

Или используйте X2Go, XSpice и XVnc вместо xrdp. spice перспективней на мой взгляд.

Но лучше наверное проверенный x2go

Comment: Первое не работает, так как авторизация идёт через XRDP и там нету выбора. Второе не подходит, так как требуется подключатся через обычный Windows RDP

Comment: @СергейРыжков добавил в ответ как переключить командой